# Event Listener Property not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, html

I have a few links that are links through JavaScript. The first one was working, and I just copied the code and changed the names, but the second one is not working. I've looked at it and it's exactly the same as the one prior, which works, so I don't know what's going on.

HTML:

```
    <a id="Home">Home</a> &nbsp&nbsp||&nbsp&nbsp

    <a href="account.php">Hamburger7</a> &nbsp&nbsp||&nbsp&nbsp

    <a id="Logout">Logout</a>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var Home_Link = document.getElementById("Home");
    Home_Link.addEventListener('click', Home, true);

    function Home() {
        window.location.href = "index.php";
    }

    var Login_Link = document.getElementById("Login");
    Login_Link.addEventListener('click', Login, true);

    function Login() {
    window.location.href = "-login.php";
    }

    var Logout_Link = document.getElementById("Logout");
    Logout_Link.addEventListener('click', Logout, true);

    function Logout() {
        window.location.href = "logout-redirect.php";
    }


</script>
```

I've edited it to include the reason for the problem (I didn't think it was a problem) and I've found the problem. Could someone tell me why it's a problem?

The problem is that putting the code:

```
var Login_Link = document.getElementById("Login");
Login_Link.addEventListener('click', Login, true);

function Login() {
    window.location.href = "-login.php";
}
```

Before the last bit of code prevents the last bit of code from running. I'm assuming it's because there's no id named "Login" in this version of the page. Why does it do that and what's a way to prevent that?

Comment: They both work here: http://jsfiddle.net/8NQfU/ Is your script block  after the elements in question?

Comment: You really should use the `href` attribute of those links instead of such JavaScript snippets

Comment: I read somewhere on StackOverflow that using the href attribute is bad if there's no link.

Comment: I found the problem. I've edited it to include the reason for the problem (I didn't think it was a problem). Could someone explain why that's a problem and what to do about it, besides moving the code around?

Comment: It's an error to attempt to call a method that doesn't exist, or to read properties of an object that doesn't exist. Before you do anything else, locate the developer tools built into your web browser, and open them. There's an error console that will tell you what's going on.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the insight. I suppose it doesn't skip it, but instead terminates the entire script at an unfound ID?

Comment: _"I read...that using the href attribute is bad if there's no link"_ - I disagree with this, because if you _do_ use an href, even just `href="#"`, then the anchor is usable from the keyboard: you can tab to it and pressing enter triggers the click event to call your JS, so your webpage is accessible for people who can't or don't use a mouse or other pointing device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"It turns out, the script is hanging at the `document.getElementById()` where the ID does not exist...If someone could explain exactly why it hangs at an unfound ID, that would be enlightening"*

The `getElementById()` function returns `null` if no element is found with the specified id. That is not in itself an error and doesn't cause the script to crash. The following line:

```
var Login_Link = document.getElementById("Login");
```

..."works" in the sense that it doesn't crash, but if there is no element with that id then `Login_Link` is set to `null`, so then when you try to do this:

```
Login_Link.addEventListener('click', Login, true);
```

...it is like saying:

```
null.addEventListener('click', Login, true);
```

And *that* gives you `TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null`. Note that this (or a similar) error message would be displayed in your browser's console, which you can see by pressing F12 in Chrome and IE, or ctrl-shift-k in FF.

If your page is set up in such a way that the element might not be there then you just need to test for `null`:

```
var Login_Link = document.getElementById("Login");
if (Login_Link != null) {
    Login_Link.addEventListener('click', Login, true);
}
```

Note that for the code you've shown there should be no need to use JavaScript at all - if the only thing your click event handlers do is set `window.location.href` to some address then you might as well just lose the JS and set `href="index.php"` (or whatever address) in the anchor elements.

Even if you intend to do something more complicated in your JavaScript click handler, I'd still suggest at least setting `href="#"` (or `href="javascript:void(0)"` if you feel you must), because anchor elements that have an `href` attribute are usable from the keyboard - that is, users who can't or don't use a mouse or other pointing device can tab to the anchor and "click" it by pressing enter.

Comment: This really explains a lot. Thanks! It's very enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

your second link has no id attribute:

```
<a href="account.php">Hamburger7</a> &nbsp&nbsp||&nbsp&nbsp
```

and your script is expecting an id attribute:

```
var Login_Link = document.getElementById("Login");
Login_Link.addEventListener('click', Login, true);

function Login() {
    window.location.href = "-login.php";
}
```

so, change the link, and ad an id attribute:

```
<a href="account.php" id="login">Hamburger7</a> &nbsp&nbsp||&nbsp&nbsp
```

Comment: The "Login" tag is for a page where the user has not logged in. It turns out, the script is hanging at the `document.getElementById()` where the ID does not exist. In order to circumvent this problem, I enclosed it in the `if` statement, `if (document.getElementById("Login") != null) {}` If someone could explain exactly why it hangs at an unfound ID, that would be enlightening.